# Stopping thread and disconnecting indy tcp client on form close

Tags: indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tthread

I do write an app, that uses Indy 10 TCP/IP Client and `TThread`. The app connects to the server on `Form.OnCreate` event and disconnects from it on `Form.OnClose` event. Connection to the server is realized in `TThread`.

When I do start the app while ethernet cable is disconnected and try to close app until connection time out, then I do get these two exeptions:

- Socket.Error #10038Socket operation on non-socket.
- Thread Error: The handle is invalid(6).

If I try to close app while it is connected to client, then I get only this exeption:

- Thread Error: The handle is invalid(6).

If I close the app while thread executes sleep, then no exeptions I do get.

What am I doing wrong, or it is normal behavior?

`TThread` class code:

```
type
  connThread = class (TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute ; override;
  private
    procedure Sinchronizuot(zinute : string; spalva : TColor; tmrNormalReconn : Boolean);
  end;
```

`Form.OnCreate` code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fellnerConn := connThread.Create(True);
  fellnerConn.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  fellnerConn.Start;
end;
```

`Form.OnClose` code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if fellnerConn <> nil then
    fellnerConn.Terminate;
  if idCl.Connected then
  begin
    try
      idCl.Disconnect;
      idCl.IOHandler.Free;  
    finally
      if fellnerConn <> nil then
      begin 
        fellnerConn.WaitFor;
        fellnerConn := nil;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Thread execute code:

```
procedure connThread.Execute;
var
  zinute : string;
  spalva : TColor;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Form1.fellnerConn.Terminated do
  begin
    zinute := 'Jungiamasi prie Moxa serverio ' + Form1.idCl.Host;
    spalva := clYellow;
    Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        Sinchronizuot(zinute, spalva, False);
      end
    );
    try
      Form1.idCl.Connect;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        zinute := e.Message + ' Nepavyko prisijungti.';
        spalva := clWebRed;
        Synchronize(procedure
          begin
            Sinchronizuot(zinute, spalva, False);
          end);
        Sleep(1000);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket error is to be expected. The main thread is closing the socket while the worker thread is still using it.

But, you cannot use `TThread.WaitFor()` with `FreeOnTerminate=True`, that is why you keep getting "the handle is invalid" errors. The thread object is being destroyed, closing its handle, while `WaitFor` is still using it.

You should not be using `FreeOnTerminate` like this. It should only be used for start-and-forget type of threads. As soon as you need to keep a reference to a thread object, you should not use its `FreeOnTerminate` property anymore.

Either way, you should be using the thread's `OnTerminate` event so you can `nil` your reference to the thread as soon as the thread has terminated.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  connThread = class (TThread)
  protected
    FClient: TIdTCPClient;
    procedure Execute; override;
  private
    procedure Sinchronizuot(zinute : string; spalva : TColor; tmrNormalReconn : Boolean);
  public
    constructor Create(Client: TIdTCPClient); reintroduce;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fellnerConn := connThread.Create(IdCl);
  fellnerConn.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  fellnerConn.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if fellnerConn <> nil then
    fellnerConn.Terminate;
  try
    idCl.Disconnect;
  finally
    if fellnerConn <> nil then
    begin 
      fellnerConn.OnTerminate := nil;
      fellnerConn.WaitFor;
      FreeAndNil(fellnerConn);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fellnerConn := nil; 
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, Sender.Free);
end;

constructor connThread.Create(Client: TIdTCPClient);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FClient := Client;
end;

procedure connThread.Execute;
var
  zinute : string;
  spalva : TColor;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    zinute := 'Jungiamasi prie Moxa serverio ' + FClient.Host;
    spalva := clYellow;
    Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        Sinchronizuot(zinute, spalva, False);
      end
    );
    try
      FClient.Connect;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        zinute := e.Message + ' Nepavyko prisijungti.';
        spalva := clWebRed;
        Synchronize(procedure
          begin
            Sinchronizuot(zinute, spalva, False);
          end
        );
        if Terminated then Exit;
        Sleep(1000);
        Continue;
      end;
    end;
    try
      // use FClient as needed... 
    finally
      FClient.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy for the answer, but now i do get two exeptions at line `FClient.Connect;`: `Project test.exe raised exeption class EConvertError with message '''is not a valid integer value'.` and `Could not bind socket. Address and port are alredy in use.`

Comment: The changes I made did not affect `Connect()`, so any errors with it must have already been present from the beginning. But `Connect()` should not be raising any `EConvertError` exception into your code. Are you seeing that error when your app is running inside or outside of the debugger? What does the call stack look like when it is raised? As for the `bind` error, the only way you could be getting that from `TIdTCPClient` is if you are using its `BoundIP` and/or `BoundPort` property (which you shouldn't be in most situations), and the specified IP:Port is already bound to by another socket.

Comment: For a test purpose i have made completly new project, where i did put only yours code and `TListBox` to store the messages. `EConvertError` is seen when app is running in debugger mode. I do not use `BoundIP` and `BoundPort`, just `Host` and `Port`. Anyway, i have deleted `TIdTCPClient` and added a new one with same parameters and app works as charm. Thank you very much for your time, i need todo some readings now.

Comment: Unless the `EConvertError` is actually escaping from `Connect()` into your code, then don't worry about it.  The debugger sees all exceptions before code does.  Just ignore it and move on, and optionally configure the debugger to ignore `EConvertError`.  As for `TIdTCPClient`, you might consider creating it dynamically inside the thread at runtime instead of placing it on a Form at design-time.